# Passing php objects to Javascript without exposing php object values in page source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an **index.php**, a **navbar.php** **landingpage.php**, and a **landingpage.js**

The **navbar.php** file is where I retrieve user information upon successful login on **index.php** As shown below, I use `if-else` to select which navigation items to display per user. In this case, we have **Settings** navigation item.

**navbar.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';
    require_once 'dbutil/dbconnection.php';
    require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
    require_once 'functions/redirect.php';
    $user = new User();
    $user->setId($_SESSION['userId']);
    $user->setUsername($_SESSION['username']);
    $user->setPassword($_SESSION['password']);
    $user->setLastname($_SESSION['lastname']);
    $user->setFirstname($_SESSION['firstname']);
    $user->setMiddleinitial($_SESSION['middlename']);

    $role = new Role();
    $role->setRoleId($_SESSION['roleId']);
    $role->setRolename($_SESSION['rolename']);
?>

<?php if ($role->getRolename() === 'Administrator') : ?>
    <a class="nav_tab" id="admin_settings" href="#">
       Settings
    </a>
<?php endif; ?> ....
```

**landingpage.php** has the **navbar.php** attached to it.

```
<?php
require_once 'navbar.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin | Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dashboard_admin.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- CONTENT CONTAINER's content depends on what was clicked on navbar -->
    <!-- this div gets filled with different content/page depending on what was clicked on the navbar. -->
    <!-- end of container-->
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var user = '<?php echo json_encode($user);?>';
    var role = '<?php echo json_encode($role); ?>';
</script>
<script src="js/landingpage.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**GOAL:** I had to pass the php `$user` variable and `$role` to **landingpage.js** (in other words, make their values visible within the **landingpage.js**)

**PROBLEM:** The way I have it setup to make $user and $role variables' values visible in **landingpage.js**, exposes `$user` and `$role` properties when you view the page source code. I can't think of another way or setup to pass php objects `$user` and `$role` values to my **external javascript** file without exposing its properties.

[image]

The reason I am passing the `json_encode($user)` and `json_encode($role)` to **landingpage.js** is so that I can show or hide parts of the landing page depending on the role of user who is logged in.

**landingpage.js**

```
var userObj = JSON.parse(user);
var roleObj = JSON.parse(role);

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadDashboard();
});

function loadDashboard() {
    var url_admin_dashboard = 'view/admin_dashboard.php';
    var url_teacher_dashboard = 'view/teacher_dashboard.php';
    var url_student_dashboard = 'view/student_dashboard.php';
    div_content_container.html('');
    if (roleObj.rolename === 'Administrator') {
        div_content_container.load(url_admin_dashboard);
    } else if (roleObj.rolename === 'Teacher') {
        div_content_container.load(url_teacher_dashboard);
    } else if (roleObj.rolename === 'Student') {
        div_content_container.load(url_student_dashboard);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long description. I'm fairly new with integration of PHP AJAX and JQuery and still trying to really understand how to properly setup the pages to avoid repetition of codes.

I'd appreciate any suggestion. I just thought that it's really wrong to expose the php object values during `json_encode()`

Thank you.

Comment: Surely if you only need the users Role, then thats all you need to pass to the browser

Comment: What’s wrong with that? If you don’t use a template engine you will always do an `echo something` in some point.

Comment: Just saying you shouldn't use plaintext for your passwords.

Comment: Well in first case you shouldn’t store the password in the session.

Comment: @muecas where or how should I store the password?

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve. Why you store the password in a session? To verify the user?

Comment: @muecas Yes, just to verify the user.

Comment: Once you have the user name and password verified after the login, and created a session, you could store some not sensitive data in the session that permits to verify the user. From that point on the data will be always available on the php session. You don’t need to print it out on the html to use it on any ajax call or any php script execution. Only by starting the session, the data will be there to use on server side. Why you would print the data on the html? What for? If just to verify the user you could use just the session.